# Android - Permission denial for media provider; WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE already added

Tags: android, android-intent, share, android-permissions

I'm trying to share an image from my Android app (Java).

The image I'm trying to share has already been loaded to an image view in the fragment.

I found several solutions and in average this is what they suggest;

```
Bitmap bitmap = movieImage.getDrawingCache();
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title", null);
            

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//without the below line intent will show error
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My subject line");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, movie.getName());
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via..."));
```

and the problem is always the same:

```
Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=10795, uid=10078 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

This is already in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: From where did you load it in the view? You better share it from that place too.

Comment: `and the problem is always the same:` Which statement causes that message?

Comment: @blackapps the error is caused by MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage

Comment: Then why did you post all that code after it? Confusing.